# How to factorise $2 \sin^2θ – 3\sinθ +1 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

This is trigonometry from double angles and compound angles. Thus far I've simplified it up to this point. $$2 \sin^2θ – 3\sinθ +1 = 0$$

I'm trying to factorize this to solve for General Solution. I tried taking out a common but that +1 is giving me a problem. I used the quadratic equation to get 1 and 0.5 as an answer, but i don't know how to write it in terms of 2sin(squared)θ and -3sinθ.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $x = \sin \theta$, and then factor the resulting quadratic.

$$2x^2 -3x +1= 0 \iff  (2x -1)(x-1)= 0$$

Now, replace $x$ with $\sin \theta$ to get $2\sin \theta = 1$ or $\sin \theta = 1 \iff\sin \theta = \frac 12,$ or $\sin \theta = 1$.

Comment: Yes, i made it to 2x^2 -3x +1 =0
but i don't how how to exactly factorize this. The +1 is giving me problems.

Comment: If the factors don't appear readily to you, you can always use the quadratic formula to solve for the roots $x = \sin\theta$.

Comment: @SulaimaanManack  To split the linear term of $2x^2 - 3x + 1$, we must find two numbers with product $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ and sum $-3$.  They are $-2$ and $-1$.  Hence, \begin{align*} 2x^2 - 3x + 1 & = 2x^2 - 2x - x + 1 && \text{split the linear term}\\ & = 2x(x - 1) - 1(x - 1) && \text{factor by grouping}\\ & = (2x - 1)(x - 1) && \text{extract the common factor} \end{align*}

Comment: @N.F Taussig (+1) I was going to type exactly that. I'm terrible at seeing factors without this method.