# How do I solve $3\sin t=18(1-\sin ^2t)$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve $$3\sin t=18(1-\sin ^2t)$$

Because, $$3\sin t=18(1-\sin ^2t)$$ is like quadratic, but using ABC I get not special angles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to factorise $2 \sin^2θ – 3\sinθ +1 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185627/how-to-factorise-2-sin2%ce%b8-3-sin%ce%b8-1-0)

Comment: Is there any reason for you to think the answer should be special angles?